Pandas multilevel Pivot/Transpose
I've looked thru countless examples, but I cannot figure out how to do the below.
Any tips would be greatly appreciated
Original df (note the multilevel)
  Gender        A          B  
            sum count    sum count
0  M         10  1        50 14  
1  F         20  3         5  2    

I want to pivot/transpose to this multilevel df:
  Gender        M          F  
            sum count    sum count
0  A         10   1       20  3  
1  B         50  14        5  2    

I tried all sorts of pivoting, melting, transposing but can't get this simple result.

Assuming "Gender" a secondary index level, you have several options, but you need to stack/unstack:
df.droplevel(0).unstack().unstack([2, 1])

Or:
df.droplevel(0).stack(0).unstack(0).swaplevel(axis=1)

Output:
         F   M     F     M
       sum sum count count
Gender                    
A       20  10     3     1
B        5  50     2    14

variants
For your exact output you need a bit of post-processing:
out = (df.droplevel(0).unstack().unstack([2, 1])
         .sort_index(axis=1, level=0, ascending=False,
                     sort_remaining=False)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=['Gender', None])
      )

Output:
Gender   M         F      
       sum count sum count
A       10     1  20     3
B       50    14   5     2

If "Gender" is initially a column, you first need to move it as index:
df.set_index('Gender').droplevel(0).unstack().unstack([2, 1])
# or any other variant

Reproducible inputs:
# "Gender" as index
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'index': [(0, 'M'), (1, 'F')],
 'columns': [('A', 'sum'), ('A', 'count'), ('B', 'sum'), ('B', 'count')],
 'data': [[10, 1, 50, 14], [20, 3, 5, 2]],
 'index_names': [None, 'Gender'],
 'column_names': [None, None]}, 'tight')

# "Gender" as column
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'index': [0, 1],
 'columns': [('Gender', ''),
             ('A', 'sum'),
             ('A', 'count'),
             ('B', 'sum'),
             ('B', 'count')],
 'data': [['M', 10, 1, 50, 14], ['F', 20, 3, 5, 2]],
 'index_names': [None],
 'column_names': [None, None]}, 'tight')


Thank you, this is perfect and I appreciate the way you covered all the cases.
The mistake I was making when using stack/unstack was I wasn't setting the level for the calls.
Ie, stack() vs stack(0) and unstack() vs unstack(0).
